Problem with setting set nocount on/off through the procedure
I want to save the setting of ANSI parameters on PC and later, after some job and changing some parameters to put it back on the original setting that I saved in global temp table.
For this purpose, I created 2 procedures: SaveAnsi and BringBackAnsi.
CREATE PROCEDURE SaveAnsi
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(1000);
        DECLARE @Insert NVARCHAR(1000);
        DECLARE @I INT;
        DECLARE @table VARCHAR(30);
        SELECT
            @I = @@SPID; --I will make global temporary table with SPID
        SET @table = '##AnsiSet' + CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(10));
        SET @DynamicSQL = N'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + N'(NAME varchar(50),STATUS bit)';
        EXEC sp_executesql
            @DynamicSQL;
        SELECT
             *
        INTO #Ansi
        FROM
             (
                 SELECT
                     name,
                     [Status] = CASE
                                    WHEN (@@OPTIONS & number) = 0
                                        THEN
                                        '0'
                                    ELSE
                                        '1'
                                END
                 FROM
                     master.dbo.spt_values
                 WHERE
                     type = 'SOP'
                     AND number > 0
             ) AS X;

        SET @Insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ' SELECT * FROM #Ansi';
        EXEC sp_executesql @Insert;

    END;

create PROCEDURE dbo.[BringBackAnsi] @SPID VARCHAR(10)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Tabel VARCHAR(30);
        DECLARE @Select NVARCHAR(1000);
        DECLARE @Setting NVARCHAR(1000);
        SET @Select = N'';
        SET @Setting = N'';
        SET @Tabel = '##AnsiSet' + @SPID;
        CREATE TABLE #Temp
            (
                Con INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                Name  VARCHAR(30),
                Status INT
            );

        SET @Select = N'insert into #Temp(Name,Status) select Name,Status from ' + @Tabel;
        EXEC sp_executesql @Select;
        DECLARE @b INT;
        DECLARE @bmax INT;
        DECLARE @Status INT;
        DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(30);
        SET @b = 2;
        SET @Name = '';
        SELECT
            @bmax = MAX(Con)
        FROM
            #Temp;
        WHILE @b <= @bmax
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @Name  = Name,
                    @Status = Status
                FROM
                    #Temp
                WHERE
                    Con = @b;
                IF @Status = 1
                    SET @Setting = N'set ' + @Name + N' ON;';
                ELSE
                    SET @Setting = N'set ' + @Name + N' OFF;';
        EXEC sp_executesql @Setting;
                PRINT @Setting;
                SET @b = @b + 1;
            END;
        DROP TABLE #Temp;
    END;

But the result for some reason is not good.
Firstly, I will call procedure EXEC SaveAnsi to save original setting
EXEC SaveAnsi
--now I will change one of the settings

SET NOCOUNT ON --In my case this setting was on off firstly

--Now I will check SPID, becouse it is input parameter for second procedure 
SELECT @@SPID --check SPID, because I use it for making temporary table in this case its 543

-- Now, I will call second procedure because I want to bring back original settings
EXEC BringBackAnsi 543

The result is not good, because when I check what setting is now in system, it brings not original, but changed result:
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  name,
        [Status] = CASE WHEN (@@OPTIONS & number) = 0 THEN '0' ELSE '1' END
    FROM    master.dbo.spt_values 
    WHERE       type='SOP'
        AND number > 0
) AS X

For some reasons, second procedure doesn't restore original settings.
I tried to debug procedure and saw that it change setting only inside procedure, but when you call it outside, for some reasons it don't work.
What can be the problem here?

What are you trying to do in the first place and why? SET is only used to set script options, not server or database-wide options. The options added by script generators are typically the defaults already used by all databases. Some of these options exist only for compatibility with pre-2005 databases. Some can't be set to non-ANSI settings any more.

SET NOCOUNT ON only lasts for the current scope e.g. the stored procedure, once you leave the current scope it reverts back to whatever it was in the outer scope.

Whatever it is you are trying to do you almost certainly don't need to. Firstly the SET options reset as soon as you leave the scope or close the session (unless you use sp_configure which you shouldn't do). Secondly most of the settings shouldn't be touched anyway, why do you feel they need changing?

Thank you all guys for quick answers. I think that you give me answer on my question. Now, why I need this? Well, lets say that I deal with a lot of companies with some software. The problem is in the fact that companies don't have same settings on their computers and I am not administrator of that PCs. The idea was that I firstly set some settings and later, after some activity to bring them back, because some other procedures may need original setting. Now I realized that it is not possible. Thank you a lot!!!
